# OS X Finder Batch Rename Stored Last Find Text Bug

Tags: macos, finder

Accidentally, I pasted in an enormous amount of text into OS X Finder's batch file rename dialog's find field. Now I can't seem to overwrite the find text field contents - see below:

[image: Screenshot of OS X Finder Replace Dialog]

Any ideas about how I might get around this problem? Does anyone know where the last find field contents might be stored?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Copy some small amount of text to the clipboard. Then open up the Finder Rename dialog. Then click Edit-Select All and Edit-Paste. This will override the last stored find text. For some reason this doesn't seem to work using the keyboard shortcuts.